# How to use ngx-translate in Akveo Nebular auth components

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, nebular

I'd like to add multilingual support to an Angular application that uses Nebular UI kit. I've installed and configured `ngx-translate` module and it loads the translations fine. However, I'm having troubles to make it work in the authentication components. I'll try to explain it with an example:

I'm using custom components that inherit the Nebular base ones. For example, my login component is declared as follows:

`export class LoginComponent extends NbLoginComponent implements OnInit {`

I need to inject the ngx-translate `TranslateService` into it, so the constructor should be something like this:

```
constructor(service: NbAuthService, options: {}, cd: ChangeDetectorRef, router: Router, translate: TranslateService) {
    super(service, {}, cd, router); 
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for LoginComponent in
>   /home/felip/projects/wfront/src/app/auth/login/login.component.ts:
>   (?, ?, [object Object], ?, [object Object])

To avoid messing with the constructors, I also tried to use Angular's `Injector` to access the needed service:

**app.module.ts**

```
export let AppInjector: Injector;
```

**login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent extends NbLoginComponent implements OnInit {
  translate = AppInjector.get(TranslateService);
  /* ... */
```

**login.component.html**

```
<h1 id="title" class="title">{{ "AUTH.TITLE" | translate }}</h1>
```

This works, and I see the text in the language that I define with `translate.use()` in the constructor of the application main component. However, when I change the language in runtime, the translations are not updated. I'm sure it has to do with the way I've injected  `TranslateService`, but I don't know how I could solve it.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The injection error occurs because you're not using the `NB_AUTH_OPTIONS` injection token to resolve `options`.  The constructor should look like

#### login.component.ts

```js
constructor(authService: NbAuthService, @Inject(NB_AUTH_OPTIONS) options = {}, 
  cd: ChangeDetectorRef, router: Router, translate: TranslateService) {
    super(authService, options, cd, router);
}
```

Working example

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/nebular-dynamic-auth-api-tj5uey

Nebular Source

> https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/master/src/framework/auth/components/login/login.component.ts